# iTunes Connect complains about my Xamarin Forms app "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I submitted a Xamarin Forms iOS application to the App Store, but received the following email:

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSContactsUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose....
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with
>   a user-facing purpose...
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with
>   a user-facing purpose...
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with
>   a user-facing purpose
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSSiriUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code
>   references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
>   Info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key
>   with a user-facing purpose

However I'm not using any of the permissions mentioned above. My only Nuget references are

```
Acr.UserDialogs
Newtonsoft.Json
SharpZipLib
```

I added the missing strings to the info.plist and resubmitted the App. Didn't get the email but Apple still rejected it, asking for further information regarding how the app uses the requested permissions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you do not have the "Mono Linker" enabled in release mode

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you so much! Setting the linker behavior to "Link All" did the trick.

Comment: we still see this issue - even with <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was related to the "Mono Linker". A million thanks to @SushiHangover in the comments above for pointing it out.

If anyone is experiencing the same problem, simply go to the iOS project options and set the linker to "Link All" as shown below:

[image]

Comment: You can mark this answer later which can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: If all nugets that uses these permissions are cleared out - then "Missing Purpose String" should not happen?
Also in the docs: "Use Link All with care as you may have to manually preserve some classes and/or methods to avoid runtime failures due to missing code": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos

Comment: Is there a way to find out what permissions are used from all solution's libraries or SDKs ?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! My Xamarin Forms IOS app was passing the Apple upload validation process but wasn't visible in testflight. I was scratching my head, I tried changing the Linker settings to "Link All" from "Don't Link" and that fixed the issue.. I had a gotten a email from apple saying that my app was missing several purpose strings in my info.plist file such as microphone and contacts etc just like the poster of this thread...