# iOS IPA is not a valid Binary

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store

I am using Xamarin Forms to develop an iPhone app, everything is working fine, from development & debugging to creating an Archive for App Store Deployment.

When I uploaded the .ipa to the App Store for Review I got an Invalid Binary Error with a detailed description saying I needed to put

1. NSCalendarsUsageDescription
2. NSContactsUsageDescription
3. NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
4. NSAppleMusicUsageDescription
5. NSSiriUsageDescription
6. NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
7. NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
8. NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
9. NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription

**I am not using any of these services in my App but I am still getting this error from Apple Review.**

I also checked **info.plist file & provision file** there also I have not mentioned any of the above services.

Has anyone faced the same issue? or do let me know what more details are required from my side for you all to solve this issue. :)

Comment: Did you use any third-party library?  This may be due to some service access code in third party library even though you don't request the permission. Adding these key value pairs in info.plist file may fix your problem.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT thanks for your attention i resolved my problem now & have posted the answer.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please consider accepting your answer which may help others with similar questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it will be allowed tomorrow for me to mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem by changing Linker Behavior from

**Don't Link ->  Link Framework SDKs Only**

For some people If the issue still exists try changing the Linker Behavior from

**Don't Link ->  Link All**

You can get this setting from

**iOS Project -> Properties -> iOS Build**

Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979322/itunes-connect-complains-about-my-xamarin-forms-app-missing-purpose-string-in-i?rq=2) from where I resolved my issue.